# Use QTimer outside QObject

Tags: c++, qt, timer, qtimer

So, I've written my own class `Personages`. It has a function `kill()`, that makes Personage to be "dead".

```
void Personages::kill()
{
    this->alive = false;
}
```

What I want to do is after it has been killed, call a timer to make Personage alive again in 1 second. To call a function like this:

```
void Personages::reincarnate()
{
    this->alive = true;
}
```

I make this project in Qt and I've tried to use a QTimer, but, as I understood, it can be used only with `QObject` (my class isn't `QObject`). So my question is how can I achieve this?

```
 void Personages::kill()
    {
        this->alive = false;
        ????
    }
```

---

Okey, I've tried just to make it to be `Q_OBJECT`. class Personages is child-class of other class:

```
class Personages : public Objects
```

So, in `Objects.h` I've done the following:

```
class Objects: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
}
```

Now Personages is Q_OBJECT too, am I right?
Personages has these functions (.h):

```
    void            kill();
private slots:
    void            reincarnate();
```

And here is the code:

```
void Personages::kill()
{
    this->alive = false;
    this->timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(this->timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(reincarnate()));
    this->timer->start(1000);
}

void Personages::reincarnate()
{
    this->alive = true;
    this->timer->stop();
    delete this->timer;
}
```

It compiles but still the dead personage doesn't become alive. What is the problem?
I have this error:
QObject::connect: No such slot Objects::reincarnate() in ..\AndenturesOfLolo\personages.cpp:1074

---

Okey, I don't need to do any class to be a Q_OBJECT. Ali's answer worked exactly as I wanted

```
void Personages::kill()
{
    this->alive = false;
    QTimer::singleShot(5000, [=]() { reincarnate(); });
}

void Personages::reincarnate()
{
    this->alive = true;
}
```

Comment: Any reason to not to just make your class a QObject?

Comment: @MrEricSir I've tried. Code compiles, but doesn't work. I've updated the question with my attempt

Comment: Do you have a Qt event loop running?

Comment: @MatteoItalia in main.c I have these: QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
QTimer::singleShot(2000, [=]() { foo(); });
```

Comment: can you explain, second part mean? is it some kind  of lamba-function in c++?

Comment: Yes, it is a lambda. I think you can pass pointer to a static function too (not tried, but it should work).

Answer (score 0):

> Now Personages is Q_OBJECT too, am I right?

No, `Personages` does not inherit `Q_OBJECT` from `Objects` but needs to be `Q_OBJECT` as well for the slot `reincarnate` to be recognized. Making the super class of `Personages` a `Q_OBJECT` does not make `Personages` a `Q_OBJECT` class - if it did then you would never have to declare a `QObject`-derived class as  `Q_OBJECT`, and similarly you would never be able to make a `QObject` subclass that *wasn't* a `Q_OBJECT` class.

Try adding the `Q_OBJECT` line to your definition for `Personages` and see if that works.